# Checkboxes to generate letter

Tags: vba, checkbox, text, ms-word

I am currently building a [User form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldOtx.png) for some letters we use at work and I would like to design the userform to generate the letter with mostly just checkboxes. e.g.

> Your application cannot be completed until the following is received:
> A Statutory declaration providing a statement in regards to your: financial situation

In the above example I would need two checkboxes.

Checkbox 1:

> A statutory declaration providing a statement in regards to your:

Checkbox2:

> financial situation

I guess the question I am asking is in two parts:

1: How do I get checkboxes to generate text?

2: How do I get multiple checkboxes to generate text against the same bookmark/s?

I may not need a Statutory Declaration, I may need a "certified copy of:" ---"bank details, proof of identity, proof of citizenship"

As you can tell from the user form it's pretty extensive and all the checkboxes in the lower half of the form need to generate text.
Grateful for any advice or direction or resources or anything.

Comment: A checkbox can't generate text. However, based on a checkbox a text deposited in, say, a textbox or a label, can be inserted in a document or left out. This bit would be done by code. If you use option buttons you can extend this idea to "either/or", and if you use a multiple choice listbox you can just click half a dozen key words and let the code write the letter for you. The trick is to have the text in one location, a trigger in another and code that evaluates and acts on the trigger to put it all together.

Comment: Thanks for that @Variatus can you put that up as an answer so I can select it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you might store the text to be inserted in your letter in the Check box's caption property and use code to insert the text into your letter when the box is checked. I think this is cumbersome and recommend that you use the caption for a caption, for example, "Statutory declaration". If it is checked such a paragraph is inserted into the letter, else it is left out.

The required declaration may include one or several of many items. Since you are thinking of check boxes, you could have one for each "bank details", "proof of identity", "proof of citizenship". These selections are very short and could be placed in the caption property. But if the texts are longer or of greatly varying lengths I would recommend the use of text boxes instead. So, if Cbx1 is clicked, the text of Tbx1 is inserted etc.

Alternatively, if only one item is required you might consider a dropdown. Or you might use a list box with multiple choices. In principle, I think that using different systems for different levels of decision making helps the user to find his way through your form. For example, use check boxes to select paragraphs (the full text of which might be shown in adjacent text boxes), and then switch to list boxes, option buttons, dropdowns or check boxes which look completely different to specify the contents of the selected paragraph. All of that detail might as well be hidden until the user has checked its box.